# How to increase push-up set?

Tags: push-ups, home-exercise, calisthenics, freeweights

I started to practice push-up since two weeks ago.  Embarrassingly, I was able to do 1 set of 10 and 3 sets of 5, but now I can do 1 set of 20-25 and 3 sets of 10.  I know that is nothing, so I want to seek your advice and experience about how to do 100 pushups or 2 minutes of push-up? Is there any way to maximize push-ups?

I also feel a considerable amount of pain in my arm(biceps) after doing the sets of push-up…Whenever I raise my body above, I feel like majority of my power is focused on my two hands…Is that wrong sign?

Comment: See also https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1984/how-should-i-push-past-a-training-plateau-for-100-push-up-challenge?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/41674/my-pushups-dont-increase?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Regarding the bicep pain: There should not be any "considerable amount of pain" in your biceps. If this is problem persists, you should get it diagnosed.